# Passing data using dismissViewControllerAnimated in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segue

I have two ViewControllers. One that is the main menu of my game, called MenuViewController, and another one which is the level you play in, called ViewController.
To get to the level, from the menu, I use a segue. To go back to the menu from the level I use dismissViewControllerAnimated, like this:

```
func leaveScene() {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

What I wanted to know is, I have a variable called x for example, and I want to pass its value to the MenuViewController so I can access it there. How can this be done?

Comment: Just use an unwind segue, then you can access the ViewController there

Comment: Can you please show some code or an example for this case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [dismissModalViewController AND pass data back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203799/dismissmodalviewcontroller-and-pass-data-back)

Comment: Yes but it's in objective c and I want a simpler way to do this, in Swift!

Comment: Ok I found out the solution, but it doesnt work for my case. In my app, to dismiss the view controller, I swipe... How can I do the unwind segue with swipe?

Comment: Here is how to set up an unwind segue to be called programmatically.  Then just call it from your swipe handling routine.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/25202589/1630618

Comment: Great, it's working! Now how do I access my viewController from there?

Comment: `let sourceViewController = segue.sourceViewController as! MyViewControllerType`.  the "source" view controller is the one you are returning from.  Cast the value to the type of the viewController and then you can access its properties.

Comment: That goes in your unwind segue landing function.

Comment: You have an answer in Swift here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318480/passing-data-in-swift