# How can I delete memory? (Swift)

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, uiviewcontroller

I have 7 ViewControllers. When I am on the first ViewController, I have a method prepare for segue to push data (variables) from one to the next ViewController. When I am on the last ViewController I have an action button, which goes to the first ViewController. All this work perfectly. My problem is that more often I do that the memory increases permanently. How can I delete the memory between the last and the first ViewController in Swift?

Thank you!

Comment: Does your app crash? or what is the problem? Check if you have strong references and you can use profile instruments to see what remains

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `deinit` method to check if they deallocate.

Comment: Consider using an unwind segue to return to you first view controller. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25202589/1630618