# Memory use in Swift

Tags: swift, memory, viewcontroller

I have many ViewControllers. When I am on the initial ViewController I push data with prepareforsegue to the second ViewController. When I am on the second ViewController I push date with prepareforsegue to the third.....  When I am on the last ViewController, I want to **clear the hole memory** and go back to the first ViewController.
I have a problem with the memory: Always when I go to the next ViewController the memory increase. How can I delete this memory again?

Xcode -> Show the debug Navigator -> Memory -> Memory use

Thank you!

Comment: Is this different from your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32626023/how-can-i-delete-memory-swift ?

Comment: The memory will automatically be cleaned up once you remove all the other view controllers to the navigation stack. As mentioned by Scott Austin, use `popToRootViewController` to do this and get back to the base of the navigation stack.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a ton of detail here - but I'm assuming you've embedded your ViewControllers in a UINavigationViewController. If you use - popToRootViewController:animated:, you'll reduce the retain count of the second and third view controllers to 0. Swift's garbage collection will dump that memory at some point thereafter, although, it may not be immediate.